# How to make a HTTP POST request when the data parameter includes an ampersand?

Tags: python

I am attempting to access data on lobbying expenditures from the [LobbyView API](https://www.lobbyview.org/api-doc#!/). Per the documentation on their website, I am using a POST request to collect lobbying data for AT&T Inc and Apple Inc. When I run the following code for Apple Inc, the API returns Apple's lobbying data as expected.

```
import requests, json
query = {"legal_name": "Apple Inc"}
results = requests.post('https://www.lobbyview.org/public/api/reports', data = json.dumps(query))
print(results.json())
```

But, when I run the same code for AT&T Inc, the API returns nothing.

```
import requests, json
query = {"legal_name": "AT&T Inc"}
results = requests.post('https://www.lobbyview.org/public/api/reports', data = json.dumps(query))
print(results.json())
```

I believe the problem is that AT&T Inc includes an ampersand (&) in its name. 
**How should I adjust my code so that I can make a POST request when the data parameter includes an ampersand (&) (e.g. "AT&T Inc")?**

Comment: Your call is syntactically correct. There might be an issue with ampersands in their API.

Comment: Lobbyview offers many other ways of querying for certain companies, I'd recommend using those instead.

Comment: I've checked their API docs, which don't say anything about this. Maybe you can get in touch with them? A workaround: use `query = {"gvkey": 9899}`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try either to replace with %26 or with \&

Answer (score 0):

Your request is correct.

You can check with curl

```
curl -X POST https://www.lobbyview.org/public/api/reports -d '{"legal_name":"AT&T Inc"}'
```

returns empty record, but

```
curl -X POST https://www.lobbyview.org/public/api/reports -d '{"client_name":"AT&T Services, Inc."}'
```

returns lot of data. So the problem is not ampersand sign, most probably there is no data for AT&T Inc.